# ClientMessageInspectors are not available in Xamarin app

Tags: c#, android, wcf, xamarin, soap

I have a Xamarin.Android app that uses WCF to connect to a SOAP web service. I need to have a message inspector added so that it can supply headers to all requests before sending. The code to apply the inspector is the following:

```
public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
{
     clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(this);
}
```

The app compiles and runs, but when calling this the getter for `ClientMessageInspectors` I get a `System.NotImplementedException`:

at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime.get_ClientMessageInspectors () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher/**ClientRuntime.cs:108**

After checking the Mono file referenced in the exception stack trace, I have found that `ClientMessageInspectors` is not implemented, but `MessageInspectors` is exposed, when I try to use MessageInspectors instead in the app, it does not compile.

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: ClientMessageInspectors instead of the  MessageInspectors from .Net 5, and xamarin has the reference about .Net Standard, they are differrent. In addition, you can try to update the Mono version to check implement ClientMessageInspectors, or down the version to use MessageInspectors.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I'm using the latest mono and as you can see it's not implemented here https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/main/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher/ClientRuntime.cs
How is it possible to use MessageInspectors in the project referencing .NET Standard? as I don't think upgrading mono will be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by removing the project that contains the shared code and only use a single Android project inside the solution. After that I added System.ServiceModel version 2.0.5 from Mono and it worked fine.